# `user-emacs-directory' directory is inaccessible

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, microsoft-windows

I had recently started to get

```
Warning (initialization): Unable to access `user-emacs-directory' (~/.emacs.d/).
```

message upon startup.

I'm on

- Windows 7 (X64)
- using the latest x64 emacs-25.0.94.2 build
- and .21 spacemacs.
- My `$HOME` is set to `C:\HOME` (with the "normal" Windows environment variable way), and in which there is the .emacs.d directory and my not so tailored `.spacemacs`, which gets processed upon startup,
- and I can access via `dired ~` so I assume that it is set properly.

Could someone point me in the right direction what should I do with it?

Comment: Can you access "dired ~/.emacs.d"?  Generally I set HOME to the traditional home directory "C:\Documents and Settings\User" which is a holdover from Windows XP. On Windows 7 you could presumably update this to "C:\Users\User".  I think either of these is a better idea than the root directory.

Comment: Thanks @InHarmsWay ou had pointed out that I don't have access to ~/.emacs.d only in emacs, because for some reason it had belonged to the domain administrator's user. I had reowned it and now the warning had gone, and I have access to it. Please add your answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I set HOME to the traditional home directory

> C:\Documents and Settings\User

which is a holdover from Windows XP. On Windows 7 and later you could presumably update this (although I haven't tried this) to

> C:\Users\User

I think either of these is a better idea than something in the root directory.

Comment: I use the `C:\Users\USERNAME` setting, works fine. Emacs' default is `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming` (see [HOME and Startup Directories on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I use symlinks to link  `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d` to the actual files which are stored elsewhere. I had used:

`cmd /c mklink C:\Users\<me>\.emacs.d C:\<elsewhere>\.emacs.d`

to create the link, but you actually need to create a *hard* link to the directory (or *junction* as Windows calls them) with the `/J` flag:

`cmd /c mklink /J C:\Users\<me>\.emacs.d C:\<elsewhere>\.emacs.d`

I also created a hard link to my `.emacs` file with the `/H` flag:

`cmd /c mklink /H C:\Users\<me>\.emacs C:\<elsewhere>\.emacs`